# How to replicate the result of symbolic limit?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am trying to check whether the limit mentioned in the equation (3.5) of [this textbook](https://hef.ru.nl/%7Etbudd/docs/liealgebras.pdf) (page 14 of the PDF) does really simplify into the claimed expression.

I am trying to simplify this limit in particular:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\mathbf{1} + \alpha_a\frac{X_a}{k}\right)^k = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}\left(\alpha_aX_a\right)^m \equiv e^{\alpha_aX_a},
$$
where $X_a$ is a matrix and $\alpha_a$ is a scalar.

To make this case as simple as possible, I tried to simplify the limit using the following concrete matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

The result of the limit simplification should then be $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}$, as is mentioned in equation (3.6) of the textbook.

However, Instead of that result, MMA simplified the limit into the $2\times2$ identity matrix. This is the expression I entered into MMA:

```
A = {
  {0, -a},
  {a, 0}
}

Limit[(IdentityMatrix[2] + A/N)^N, N -> Infinity] // MatrixForm
```

How can I replicate the textbook results?

Comment: This may not matter, but avoid uppercase symbols in general, and particularly uppercase single letter symbols like A, N. N is a function in its own right (see [its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know about this. Changing `N` to `k` and `A` to `r` did not change the result, as you wrote (i.e. MMA still simplified the expression to $\mathbf{I}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`MatrixPower`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html) and [`MatrixFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixFunction.html)

```
A = {{0, -a}, {a, 0}};

Limit[MatrixPower[IdentityMatrix[2] + A/n, n], n -> Infinity] // 
  FullSimplify

(* {{Cos[a], -Sin[a]}, {Sin[a], Cos[a]}} *)

MatrixFunction[Exp, A]

(* {{Cos[a], -Sin[a]}, {Sin[a], Cos[a]}} *)
```

Comment: There is also `MatrixExp[A]`

Comment: Thank you, using `MatrixPower` did the trick. I did not expect Mathematica to require using a special function for matrix powers (I thought the `^` operator was enough). How can I be sure in the future that MMA won't provide misleading results (like the identity matrix) when simplifying arbitrary expressions? Are there any other caveats with symbolic simplification that I should be aware of?

Comment: `Power[matrix, n]` and `MatrixPower[matrix, n]` are two completely different mathematical operations. Likewise `f[matrix]` and `MatrixFunction[f, matrix]` are radically different. Mathematica cannot guess which operation you want; you need to specify the intended operation.

Comment: @BobHanlon Oh, I didn't realize there was a difference, but after reading your comment, it makes complete sense to me! So `Power[]` performs element-wise power, whereas `MatrixPower[]` performs repeated matrix multiplication.